# Why does my citizen have no actions available?

Tags: tropico-4

In Tropico 4, I received a mission to arrest the citizen with the lowest respect. Easy enough. I clicked 'view', intending on arresting the citizen in question ... but when the citizen was selected, there were no actions available for him:

[image: Screenshot of target citizen selected]

Other citizens, when I clicked on them, had the usual actions available (arrest, kill, etc.):

[image: Screenshot of other citizen]

In fact, the only citizens I could find *without* any actions available were the ones already in prison!

I'm also a little at a loss as to why he's associated with this quest as "the citizen with the lowest respect". He seems kinda respectful to me:

[image: Stats]

But that's neither here, nor there. Why does this citizen have no actions available for him? Is there a way to make them come back?

(And, if I can't, is the only way to complete this quest to either make a citizen respect me *less* than Ulises, or perhaps to wait for him to die of old age?)

Comment: No, mine was set on this one citizen. I had to wait 30 years until he retired, and then I was able to arrest him. Once you give the order, a little symbol with bars on it shows up above the citizen's head so you know there's an action in progress; as you can see in the screenshot, there's no such icon present.